# Cannot login to phpmyadmin mysql when base64_decode disabled in disabled_functions

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, php-ini, ubuntu-15.04

I Cannot login to phpmyadmin mysql when I add base64_decode in disabled_functions in php.ini on Ubuntu 15.04

What could be the reason? Is it normal behavior or I had some malicious code trying to execute?